# JSON в массив объектов

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть JSON объект

```
{
  "яблоко": {price: 10, quantity: 3},
  "груша": {price: 4, quantity: 2},
  "вишня": {price: 20, quantity: 3},
  "ананас": {price: 17, quantity: 5}
}
```

Нужно получить массив объектов, где каждый элемент это один продукт, хранить только его название и цену. Чтобы можно было с ним работать вот так:

```
mItems[0].name //яблоко
mItems[0].price //10

mItems[1].name //груша
mItems[1].price //4

mItems[3].name //ананас
mItems[3].price //17
```

Скажите пожалуйста как правильно это сделать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не знаю на сколько это правильно, но можно так:

```js
const obj = {
  "яблоко": {price: 10, quantity: 3},
  "груша": {price: 4, quantity: 2},
  "вишня": {price: 20, quantity: 3},
  "ананас": {price: 17, quantity: 5}
};

const newObj = Object.keys(obj).map(name => ({ name, price: obj[name].price }));

console.log(newObj);
```